# Getting error as 'Cannot read property scrollIntoView of null' when used scroll down code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The above error frequently occurs with the following code

```
 const [consumerMessages, setConsumerMesssages] = useState([])

 const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

 const scrollToBottom = () => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      };
 
useEffect(() => {
        scrollToBottom()
      }, [consumerMessages]);
```

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-nobel-kt87m

Why this error is occuring and WHat could be the appropriate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

Basically on the initial render the ref hasn't been attached to the DOM node as the current ref value and so `messagesEndRef.current` isn't defined yet.

## Solution

Use a null check:

```
messagesEndRef.current &&
  messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Or using [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`):

```
messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

## Demo

[image: Edit getting-error-as-cannot-read-property-scrollintoview-of-null-when-used-scroll]

Comment: OK error is gone, but, why new error 'Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.'

Comment: @Pranav I don't see that error in your or my sandbox. Is that something to do with `textMessages` or updating that state? It's the only array I see. Did that error just appear after fixing the ref access or are you doing something to trigger it? I see that you've an `useEffect` that loads some messages from local storage, this can possibly set your state to `undefined` if there is no localStorage with that key.

Comment: Yes actually it apperas only when button is clicked, If you don't mind please check again

Comment: @Pranav Yeah, I suspected as much and tried the "send message" button. I see you load from localStorage, but if the localStorage has never been used you set your `textMessage` state to undefined. Also, when saving to localStorage you need to `JSON.stringify` it, and then `JSON.parse` it when reading back out.

Comment: Well one last query... Why the last message is going so deep, I mean how can we adjust it above message button.  Is that CSS issue?

Comment: @Pranav I'm not quite sure what you mean by "last message is going so deep", but if you  are referring to the messages list going behind/underneath the input "bubble" yes, this seems very much CSS. If not this can you clarify what is "deep"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229610/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-pranav).